# Azure Redis timing out

Tags: azure, redis, timeout

We've been having problems with Redis in Azure lately. A lot of timeout errors. I had a read of http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/10/investigating-tim…

Looking at one of the CPU points I've done a "INFO CPU" and here's what it tells me:

```
used_cpu_sys:88.72
used_cpu_user:94.69
used_cpu_avg_ms_per_sec:0
server_load:0.45
event_wait:9
event_no_wait:19
```

Am I right thinking that the CPU is being killed by the OS? Server load is almost nothing but the CPU usage is high. Any ideas how to diagnose further and fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several reason for TimeOut Exception using Redis on Azure.

Here a good post that should help you

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/10/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

Comment: I've seen this, thanks. The problems magically disappeared for now.